# Convert shapefiles to geojson with OpenLayers 5

Tags: vue.js, openlayers, geojson

I'm creating a little fun project combining Vue.js and OpenLayers and I must say that I really enjoy it. I successfully implemented draw, read and even modify drawn vectors but uploading and reading uploaded shapefiles remains a mystery to me.
Now, my question is this? Does anyone have any experience integrating shapefile reader in OpenLayers version 3+ as I would like to import zipped shapefiles to map and read vector features as GeoJSON.

I did stumble upon this little project https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson and before I dig myself in implementing this functionality in existing Vue/OpenLayers app I would like to ask if there is any better solution/approach or library.

Any link, example or advice would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(not enough reputation to comment)
[shapefile.js](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js) looks promising. Also, the owner of the repo is a very well-known figure of the community, so i think it's quality software.